# Determining the memory access pattern of a program

Tags: memory-management, system-calls

I want to extract all the virtual memory addresses accessed by a program and the sequence in which these memory addresses are accessed. Is there some tool/system call on Windows(preferred) or Linux which would let me do this?

Say there is a program P which accesses memory addresses m1,m2,m3 etc. I want to log what addresses were accessed and the sequence in which these addresses were accessed. I also want to know whether the memory address belongs to stack or heap.

Thanks!

Comment: "extract" or "log"? I would suggest a tracing debugger.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart will a tracing debugger help me get the memory addresses which are dynamically allocated like malloc?                   "log" it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called a tool for dynamic binary instrumentation. A famous one, which I am currently working with is [Intel Pin](http://pintool.org/). Be warned that you have to do a lot of reading and reviewing the examples in order to produce something functional.

Comment: Thanks! I had already solved this issue but never thought of posting the answer here.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki, I am facing the same problem of generating detailed log of memory access patterns of applications (Log of memory address pattern of application). Can you please tell me how had you solved this? Thanks